# .plist in submitted app iOS not loaded data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, plist, testflight

i'm new in iOS Development and i'm developing an app that uses external .plist as resources. The problem comes when i submitted it to test flight for test; The resource .plist is not loaded but when i'm debugging in Xcode it runs perfectly and load the contents of .plist file.

I don't know what is happen, if anybody could help me i'll be thankful. Thank's

[image: CountryCodes.plist file]
[image]

Comment: Where did you put the plist and how do you load it?

Comment: I put in Resources folder and i called it in code by this way:


if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CountryCodes", ofType: "plist") {
            if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                return dict
            }
        }

Comment: When you tested, did you run it on a device or simulator?

Comment: In real device (iPhone 5s)